# How do I restrict another account from accessing a database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to make sure that only one person has access to a specific database. How to restrict other users?

Comment: First, you should check how many users there actually are for the specific database. There may only be the one. You can do this with: ```select * from master.sys.server_principals```

Comment: Hopefully you have groups setup... you would simply revoke access to all groups except ADMIN (for obvious reasons), then grant the one user access.... or better still, create a new group, add that user to the group, then grant access to that group. then in the future if you need to grant anyone else access,you simply add them to the group.  I'm of the belief that access should be dealt with on a group/role basis rather than on a specific user... in small orgs, it can be fine, but as things get larger and complicated, it spirials out of control quickly. Roles and groups are easier to maintain.

Comment: By simply not giving them rights, it's as easy as that. If your current users already have too many rights to do things they don't have to (like everyone being `sysadmin`), that would be the first thing to tackle. In SQL Server it is much easier to make sure someone has no access to something, then it is to explicitly deny them access to something they happen to have gotten access to by over-broad rights. Sysadmins, in particular, can't really be denied anything.